# Not getting response of requestMtu on Huawei deices

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, mtu, huawei-mobile-services

I am working on Android BLE, i found strange behavior on Huawei(Honor 7C) devices some times i didn't get response from requestMtu mean when i call this method onMtuChanged method never triggers, this works fine on Samsung devices but on Huawei things are not working well.

Help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

I looked into logs and what i found is that the in case i didn't have the response for MTU request i didn't get the onConnectionUpdated and onConfigureMTU logs, only configureMTU call was visible in the logs when the issue arises

```
D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: 00:60:37:39:95:BE mtu: 256 
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=00:60:37:39:95:BE interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=00:60:37:39:95:BE mtu=247 status=0
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any pending BLE operation while requesting the MTU change ? Also, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149114/request-mtu-is-not-working-in-nougat

Comment: Could you post your code? Have you checked the HCI log if the remote device actually responds to the MTU request?

Comment: @matdev it was a fresh request, means i just connect set the MTU and have no response of that call

Comment: Are you able to write on a characteristic after sending the requestMtu() ?

Comment: @matdev when i didn't get response of MTU request than i was not able to subscribe and write to device, i then disconnect and reconnect it

Comment: @Emil what i found in logs is that when the issue happens i didn't get the onConnectionUpdated and  onConfigureMTU MTU logs

Comment: Have you checked the hci log?

Comment: @ZubairAkber Do you see any error message when you do the BLE write ? Any status update in your BluetoothGattCalback.onConnectionStateChange() ?